# Javascript check random number duplicated

Tags: javascript

I have this random number from 1 to 10 and an array from 1 to 10 but missing an 8 and 2. I want JS to figure that out and push either 8 or 2 into the array.
Javascript:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 4, 7, 10];
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  while (num == arr[i]) {
    num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  }
  arr.push(num);
```

Unfortunately, it does make a new number but duplicate with the previous compared number. Please help.

Comment: `var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length) + 1);`

Comment: Why are you using random numbers if you know (or rather can determine) which numbers you need ?

Comment: because this will be in the middle of the variable being randomized so I would not know what exactly will jump out.

Answer (score 3):

You can look for the missing numbers and random an element in that array:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 4, 7, 10];

// Build array of missing numbers
var missingNumbers = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   if (arr.indexOf(i) < 0) {
       missingNumbers.push(i);
   }
}

// Pick one of them at random
var randomNumber = missingNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * missingNumbers.length)];

// Push it into the array
arr.push(randomNumber);

// Show results
console.log(randomNumber);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the solution that was asked for - a random number of the missing ones in an array. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: He just wants to add either 2 or 8 not both. Right?

Comment: @Fran He was not asking for an array with the numbers 1-10. He was asking for a random number of the missing ones in an array.

Comment: @DanielTran OPs wording is terrible in that sense but looking at OPs attempt it's more likely all missing numbers are to be added but yes, if that was the desired output then OK.

Comment: @Fran Don't think so, then the solution would be just `arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 4, 7, 8, 10];`

Comment: @Fran: The question says *"I want...(to)...push **either** 8 **or** 2 into the array.."* (the first vesrion just said 8 but the OP fixed it). So my answer was incorrect and the above is a reasonable approach to doing that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, I reworded my previous comment but cannot undo my downvote unless answer is edited again. I could edit it for the sake of correction but not sure if that is allowed?

Comment: @Fran: FWIW, I added some comments to the code, so you can do that now if you like.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Changed it now to upvote. Was very confusing, at least answer has the votes correct now.

Comment: Hey it is much difficult to understand. See my solutions there is no need to execute loop 10 times.

Comment: @SourabhSomani: If you think your solution is better, just post it (as you have done). No need to also spam another answer to say it's better.

Comment: There is a 10% that you will keep generating a new random number more than 10 times to get out of the loop. Your solution is expensive and unpredictable @SourabhSomani

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Okay I got it its really great solutions. Awesome love it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```js
var arr =[1,3,5,6,9,4,7,10];
var num=parseInt((Math.random()*10)+1)
while(arr.indexOf(num)!=-1){
num=parseInt((Math.random()*10)+1);
}
arr.push(num)
console.log(arr)
```

In above example I am taking a number randomly and checking in loop that, The number is present in the array or not

```
while(arr.indexOf(num)!=-1)
```

if number will not be there then inside loop again I am generating again a number and checking. When I got a number which is not present then the loop body will not be execute and I am pushing that number in array.

As you said that only one number you want *either 8 or 2*

Comment: You will keep random new number until you got the missing number. In this case 80% chance that you need to random another number. This is a very expensive and unpredictable solution

Comment: `parseInt` is a *terrible* way to turn a number with possible fractional portion into a whole number.

Comment: Okay got your solution that is really great.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 4, 7, 10];
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 

    while (num == arr[i]) {
     num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);  }
     arr.push(num);}
```

basically if it is duplicated, I simply put i=0 to loop again until it is unique. It might not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The function **find** returns an array filled with all the duplicated numbers. It's optimized

```js
function find(a, b) {
    let result = [];
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        let num = NumbersList[i];
            if(b[num] == 0) {
                b[num] = 1;
            } else if (b[num] == 1) {
                b[num] = 2;
                result.push(num);
            }
    }  
console.log("Duplicated numbers: " +result.length);
return result;
}

var NumbersList = new Array();
var value = 30000;

    for(let i=0; i<value; i++) {
        let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * value) + 1);
        NumbersList.push(x);
    }

var map = new Array(NumbersList.length).fill(0);

    var t0 = performance.now();
    find(NumbersList, map);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Call to find with " +value+ " numbers took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```